# How long does it take to mine obsidian with your hands?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How long would it take to mine obsidian with your hands? I also want to know how long it takes underwater. I’m sorry if you think it has to little detail. I just want to know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*A lot.*

250 seconds, according to [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Obsidian):

| Tool | Time (s) |
| --- | --- |
| By hand | 250 |
| Wooden | 125 |
| Stone | 62.5 |
| Iron | 41.7 |
| Golden | 20.85 |
| Diamond | 9.4 |
| Netherite | 8.35 |

> Times are for unenchanted tools as wielded by players with no status effects, measured in seconds.

Also, it technically wouldn't be *mining* obsidian, just *breaking* the block, as you wouldn't obtain any obsidian from it unless you use a diamond or netherite pickaxe.

[As for the water,](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Breaking#Basics_of_breaking) you need to multiply ×5 if your head is underwater, and another ×5 if your feet aren't touching the ground, for a total of 250 seconds × 25 seconds = 6250 seconds, or 1 hour and 44 minutes. That would be harsh...

Comment: Also, it takes around 26 hours to mine by hand with Mining Fatigue.

Comment: Is there any way to trap a player so that they're forced to avoid touching the ground while underwater?

Answer (score 5):

Obsidian takes 250 seconds to mine by hand, [according to the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Obsidian#Obtaining). These numbers are the same for Java and Bedrock editions. Keep in mind that mining obsidian by hand will drop nothing.

Mining blocks when underwater takes 5 times as long when standing on the ground and 25 times as long when floating ([see on the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Water#Slower_mining_speed)), for a total of 1250 seconds (almost 21 minutes) on the ground, all the way up to 6250 seconds (about 1 hour and 45 minutes) when floating.

However, the [Aqua Affinity](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Aqua_Affinity) enchantment removes this mining speed penalty when underwater.