# Is it possible to break obsidian on Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Not in survival mode, but in creative mode you can.

This applies to both Java and Bedrock

Comment: This not formatted properly as a question. If you mean to share your own knowledge, pose your question like a question and post your own answer. It's like being on Jeopardy!

Comment: Also, it's completely wrong. Of course you can break obsidian in survival mode...

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to obtain obsidian in survival Minecraft (Java edition and Bedrock edition) with a diamond or netherite pickaxe. The Efficiency enchantment is recommended as obsidian takes longer to break than most other blocks.

Comment: You need a diamond or netherite pickaxe to _obtain_ obsidian blocks. If you only want to break it, you don't even need any tools, just patience

Comment: Really? I always thought it was unbreakable without. Was that true at some point or did I just make that up?

Comment: I don't know, I've been only playing for a couple of years. Maybe it was unbreakable in older versions (?). Now it's possible, definitely. Although it takes a loooooong time: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/384819/29608

Comment: Well, I grew up on Xbox 360 edition so it maybe it is a newish thing (for me at least). I'm not too worried about editing my answer since it's closed though :/

Comment: @c1uq92 It takes a very long time and the dark colour means it's hard to see the cracks forming. But it's always been possible to destroy any mineable block with fists.

Answer (score -3):

yes but you need a diamond pickaxe a new one and a efficiency 111 picks